# How to redirect properly from one domain to another when the permalink structure of both is different?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am planning to redict one domain eg www.abc.com to www.xyz.com, the both are running on wordpress. But the first domain, which is to redirected, contains different permalink structure like www.abc.com/2012/10/4/post-name-structure/. Whereas the other domain contain no year, month, password in it. In that case it is www.xyz.com/post-name-structure/

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just redirecting the domain so that if I typed abc.com it would actually take me to xyz.com? If that is the case it has nothing to do with your WordPress install or permalink structure.

Or are you actually moving one site from abc.com to xzy.com?  After the move you should just be able to go in an resave the permalink structure and that will update the post's and page's permalink.